# learn the expected output of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, which in reality consists of more data points and days:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day_1': [0,1,1,0,1,1,0], 'day_2': [0,0,1,1,1,1,0], 'day_3': [0,1,1,1,0,0,0], 'day_4': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0], 'day_5': [1,0,1,1,1,0,0]})

    day_1    day_2    day_3    day_4    day_5
0       0        0        0        0        1
1       1        0        1        1        0
2       1        1        1        0        1
3       0        1        1        1        1
4       1        1        0        0        1
5       1        1        0        1        0
6       0        0        0        0        0
```

The zeros and ones should happen at the same indexes for consecutive days. However, due to measurement errors an expected one will sometimes be a zero.
Edit: the expected zero can also be a one. 
I would like to build a simple model that "learns" the desired behaviour and give the expected output for day 6. The desired output is (not know beforehand, but should be learned by the model):

```
    day_6   
0       0  
1       1 
2       1
3       1 
4       1 
5       1      
6       0
```

I know this can be done by various machine learning options. However, I'd like to implement the code in a small microcontroller, so I was wondering if there is a way to do this without using a lot of computational power.

Comment: Can you add expected output of all columns?

Comment: @jezrael i had a typo in the expected output. The expected output will be one columns based on the data of all days. E.g.  in day one there is a zero at index 3, which needed to be 1. On day two there is a zero on index 1 that should have been a one. I would like to detect a pattern and say before day six: probably there will be ones from index 1 to 5. Hope this makes it clear for you

Comment: It is un-clear how you get from the input to the output. For example, for row indexed 5, why do you think the output should be 1 and not 0? Please explain in an edit in the question, not as a comment here.

Comment: hmmm, is possible use `print (df.max(axis=1))` ? If not, can you change data sample for better explain it?

Comment: @jezrael you mean `df.max(axis=1)`

Comment: @Aryerez - yop, you are right, thank you.

Comment: @ jezrael, this solution of course only works when an expected one is measured as zero, as mentioned in my question. Do you know a solution if it could also be possible that an expected zero is measured as a one? For instance if df['day_5'][0] would be a one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing that you can do is:

```
test_val = 0.5 # The average value for the previous days, from which you decide the output should be 1
df['day_6'] = 1 * (df.mean(axis=1) >= test_val)
```

This will give you output of 1 in every row in which at least 50% (the `test_val` value) of the columns are 1, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I have been thinking about something similar. It can be a struggle to pick a proper value for test_val though.